# Show that only a few multiples of .01 decimal are powers of 2

Tags: number-formats

I am asking this to advance the argument that BigDecimal is better than float or double for representing exact amounts of currency.

Can someone refer me to a proof that between any two integers there are only four values that multiples of .01 and can be exactly represented in base 2?  Or at least confirm I'm correct in my belief that it's true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The four values are $25/100 = 1/4$ and its multiples.

If all you want to do is store an exact amount of currency, you can use an integer which represents the amount of cents. (This is known as fixed-point arithmetic.)

Comment: I did know what the "special" numbers are :) - It's not a homework question, but to make a case to non-cs people working with Java as a side-effect of working in Talend -  How can I show that, for example .03 doesn't have a precise representation in binary?

Comment: $0.03 = 3/100$ which cannot be written in the form $A/2^B$ and so doesn't have a precise representation in binary. To show that $3/100 = A/2^B$ is impossible, assume that $3/100 = A/2^B$ and deduce that $100A = 3 \cdot 2^B$, yet $5$ divides the LHS but not the RHS.

Comment: I don't quite follow - in particular it seems 5 is pulled out of a hat, could you just as well say 20 or 25 divides LHS?  Or 3 divides RHS?

Comment: More general, a (reduced) rational number $p/q$ can be represented exactly in base $B$ if and only if all prime factors of $q$ are prime factors of $B$. So $5$ is a prime factor of $100$ that isn't a prime factor of $2$. If you still cannot follow, I suggest you ask this specific question on math.stackexchange, since it has nothing to do with computer science.

Comment: Followed up @ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432987/how-do-we-know-p-q-can-be-expressed-as-a-terminating-fraction-in-base-b-only

Comment: Afaik, integer-cents are not precise enough in all settings. Some people (stock/money traders?) like to apply conversion rates down to parts of cents.